How to draw curl/arc around axis to indicate torque/moment rotation directions; also shade sides of solid circular cylinder

How do you draw curl/arc around an axis to indicate torque/moment rotation
Also, shade the sides of a solid circular cylinder.

Here is what I have so far.

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d, calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5, line cap=round, line join=round]

% Define colors for shading
\definecolor{cylinder-top}{RGB}{200,200,200}
\definecolor{cylinder-side}{RGB}{150,150,150}
\definecolor{cylinder-shade}{RGB}{100,100,100}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\radius}{2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\length}{8}


% Draw the shaded base ellipse (bottom of the cylinder)
\shade[color=cylinder-shade] (0,0) ellipse [x radius=\radius, y radius=0.6];

% Draw the shaded top ellipse (top of the cylinder)
\shade[color=cylinder-top] (0,\length) ellipse [x radius=\radius, y radius=0.6];

% Draw the outline of the cylinder
\draw [thick] (0,0) ellipse [x radius=\radius, y radius=0.6];
\draw [thick] (0,\length) ellipse [x radius=\radius, y radius=0.6];
\draw [thick] (-\radius,0) -- (-\radius,\length);
\draw [thick] (\radius,0) -- (\radius,\length);

% Draw the axis of rotation 
\draw [thick, latex-latex] (0,-0.2*\length) -- (0,\length+0.2*\length);

% Label the torque vectors
\node at (0,\length+0.22*\length) {$T$};
\node at (0,-0.22*\length) {$T$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Here is an image of the type of curl/arc I am interested in making to indicate rotation about an axis.

Perhaps I should be using a geometry library to make this easier?
-Thanks
